# Open html from assets by phone html viewer

Tags: android

When I click on button I want that open a html file from assets by html viewer on my android device

Comment: Did you know about WebView? If not, kindly go through this [tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/12/android-working-with-webview-building-a-simple-in-app-browser/).

Comment: HtmlViewer wil not be able to read files from the assets of your apk. Copy the file from assets to file system. Then offer the file path to an external app.

Comment: can you tell me how to do this

Comment: Just google for code. Code has been posted so often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            //Hope this will help You

             btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent = 
    new Intent(Current.this, WebView1.class);
        // Send URL for next class
                            intent.putExtra("url", "file:///android_asset/file1.html");
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    });

//*************Now define a class WebView1****************///

                public class WebView1 extends AppCompatActivity{
                private String url;
                private WebView webView;


                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                    setContentView(R.layout.web_layout);

                    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    url = intent.getStringExtra("url");


                    // Load url on webView
                        webView.loadUrl(url);   

                    }
                }
```